# Registering a user in tryit-jssip

Tags: voip, user-agent, voice, jssip, sipjs

I'm trying to register an agent in https://tryit.jssip.net/.

Attach is the screenshot for populating the data.
[JsSIP UA settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gHFzX.png)

Into the sip Uri I'm writing the information as below:
test@mypublic ip address.

What data should I enter there?

Thank you

Tried to add my public Ip address into the Sip Uri, and other data, but it doesn't show that this user agent in successfully connected. I was expecting to have a successful register.